# checking a value with a check constraint name or check clause in a database function or procedure

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

I'm working on a sql server database to populate fake data with faker-factory in python. 
Let's say I have a table named TABLE_OTHER with a column F1 of datatype int. And there is a check constraint name CHK_F1 with clause F1>0. I want to insert a data before checking on that constraint on a user defined function in the database. suppose I call that function with a value of -2 and then it would check the value using this check clause or constraint name. And it will return a status signal whether it follows the constraint or not. and then I will insert that data into that row.

So how do i use a check clause or constraint name in a stored function or procedure to verify data integrity?? 
Let me know if there is any query I'll comment right away. Thanks in advance.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU3ca.png)

Comment: ". I want to insert a data before checking on that constraint on a user defined function in the database" - that's not how they work.

Comment: `I want to insert a data before checking on that constraint on a UDF` and  `it follows the constraint or not. and then I will insert that data into that row`. So how many insert you want?

Comment: @MitchWheat is there any way I could use that constraint name or check clause??